# Filling "Educational Status" in GRE subject test application form

Tags: application, gre

I am going to apply for a GRE subject test (Mathematics). The application process is going to start in this July.

I want a suggestion regarding online filling of the application form.

One item in the form is "Educational status at the time you take the GRE test" and the options are :

Sophomore(second year),Junior(third year),Senior(fourth/final year),First-year Graduate student,Second-year Graduate student,Unenrolled(College Graduate),Unenrolled(Masters Degree),Other.

(Screenshot is given below)

[image]

Now I have completed 3 years Bachelor Degree and currently pursuing Masters(2 years). I am (and will remain at the time of taking the GRE test) in the final year of my Masters course.

So what option should I choose for the above item of the application form?

Please somebody help me. Thnx in advance.

Comment: Is this data even reported to the schools, or is it just for ETS's internal statistics?

Comment: That's the thing I am thinking about..I have no authentic information.

Answer (score 4):

If you've already completes a full year of study toward a master's degree, I'd lean towards "second-year graduate student." However, frankly I don't think schools pay a whole lot of attention to what label you use. They're much more interested in the recency and the results of the test.

Comment: Thank you so much..I also though the same..Only thing is that, is there any difference between masters degree and graduate degree in the countries like USA?

Comment: Not in any way that matters here.